# Xcode how to replace quotation from a text?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I am parsing a xml link which has lots of quotations and I wanna replace it. I have used this code but the it won't run because of the quotations. So could you help me please?

```
NSString *delete1 = [currentStringValueImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "application" " withString:@""];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape quotation symbols with '\' in your string:

```
NSString *delete1 = [currentStringValueImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" \"application\" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: Thanks it works. By the way what about replacing the wide space? for example <object type> it doesn't replace while there is a space between two letters.
Thanks.